# Does the Book of Mormon (& LDS doctrine) pass the test found in 1 John 4:2 as the true spirit of God?

Tags: lds, 1-john

Do Mormons agree that part of their trust in the book of Mormon (and the LDS church doctrine) is that it agrees with the following scriptures as a kind of litmus test is discerning the truth from the false in this world?

> This is how you can recognize the Spirit of God: Every spirit that acknowledges that Jesus Christ has come in the flesh is from God, (1 John 4:2)
>
> If anyone confesses that Jesus is the Son of God, God abides in him, and he in God. (1 John 4:15)
>
> Everyone who believes that Jesus is the Christ is born of God, and everyone who loves the Father also loves the one born of Him. (1 John 5:1)
>
> For many deceivers have gone out into the world, refusing to confess the coming of Jesus Christ in the flesh. Any such person is the deceiver and the antichrist. (2 John 1:7)

Does the LDS church “acknowledge that Jesus Christ has come in the flesh” and confess His name as the above scriptures suggest?

Comment: This question largely hinges on what it means to be [from God](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/50549/50588#50588), what it means to [believe](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/44987/45972#45972) that Jesis is the Christ [born of God](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/17364/14525) and is the [son of God](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/24937/4150). How you understand these terms largely determines how you would answer this question. According to LDS doctrine and understanding of these terms, the short answer is "Yes" the Book of Mormon does pass this test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have never heard this questions asked of Mormons before. There are doctrinal differences regarding the nature of the Trinity, etc. but this is very basic doctrine for us unless I am not fully understanding the intent of the question. First of all, we accept this truth as found in the Bible. In the Book of Mormon, a prophet named Nephi, has a vision in which he sees the following (found in 1 Nephi 11:13–21):

> "13 And it came to pass that I looked and beheld the great city of Jerusalem, and also other cities. And I beheld the city of Nazareth; and in the city of Nazareth I beheld a virgin, and she was exceedingly fair and white.
>
> 14 And it came to pass that I saw the heavens open; and an angel came down and stood before me; and he said unto me: Nephi, what beholdest thou?
>
> 15 And I said unto him: A virgin, most beautiful and fair above all other virgins.
>
> 16 And he said unto me: Knowest thou the condescension of God?
>
> 17 And I said unto him: I know that he loveth his children; nevertheless, I do not know the meaning of all things.
>
> 18 And he said unto me: Behold, the virgin whom thou seest is the mother of the Son of God, after the manner of the flesh.
>
> 19 And it came to pass that I beheld that she was carried away in the Spirit; and after she had been carried away in the Spirit for the space of a time the angel spake unto me, saying: Look!
>
> 20 And I looked and beheld the virgin again, bearing a child in her arms.
>
> 21 And the angel said unto me: Behold the Lamb of God, yea, even the Son of the Eternal Father!..."

As taught in the Church or Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints (Mormon) and which has become my own through the Holy Spirit, I know this did happen. Jesus Christ, the Creator of the earth, came, was born of a precious virgin, lived a perfect life and gave His life on the Cross to overcome physical death and my sins. I know that through Him and only through Him, I may find salvation in the Kingdom of Heavenly Father.

Comment: Welcome, and nice answer! Thanks for contributing. If you haven't already done so, I hope you'll take a minute to take the [tour] and learn [how this site is different from others](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/1809/21576).

Comment: Thanks Darren.  The intent of my question is to discern whether or not Mormons would utilize scriptures such as 1st John 4:2 as evidence that their belief in Joseph Smith & LDS scripture as the true spirit of God. My question was a little clearer until someone edited it.  Thanks again.

Comment: It's not letting me add an additional answer because of my reputation, but Christ's visit to the American people in the flesh after His Resurrection and departure from the Saints in the Old World is documented in the Book of Mormon: 3 Nephi 11-28. People are invited to feel the prints of the nails in His hands and feet, He heals the sick, institutes the sacrament, repeats some of the same sermons that He gave in the Old World, and calls 12 additional Apostles, among other things.

Answer (score 5):

David, I admire your research into the Church of Jesus Christ of Latter Day Saints, LDS, or the Mormons. :)

In the Book of Mormon we read;

> Moroni 10:32 - Yea, come unto Christ, and be perfected in him, and deny yourselves of all ungodliness; and if ye shall deny yourselves of all ungodliness , and love God with all your might, mind and strength, then is his grace is sufficient for you, that by his grace ye may be perfect in Christ; and if by the grace of God ye are perfect in Christ, **ye can in nowise deny the power of God.**
>
> Moroni 10:33 - And again, if ye by the grace of God are perfect in Christ, and deny not his power, then are ye sanctified in Christ by the grace of God, **through the shedding of the blood of Christ, which is in the covenant of the Father unto the remission of your sins,** that ye become holy, without spot.

I find it interesting that you use the word "test" in your question. As a young member of the LDS Church, we do maintain the belief in that Jesus Christ has "come in the flesh"(1John,4:2) and that he came for the remission of our sins.

As I said, I am a young member of the LDS church and I am still studying myself the Book of Mormon and other teachings of my church. I am confident that there are others on this site with more studying under their belt that may be able to answer your questions more fully. I hope I could shed a little light into what you are in search of.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome! Thanks for contributing. If you haven't already done so, I hope you'll take a minute to take the [tour] and learn [how this site is different from others](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/1809/21576).

Comment: Much appreciated NSA.

Comment: You may want to add 2 Nephi 25:26 to your answer: "And we talk of Christ, we rejoice in Christ, we preach of Christ, we prophesy of Christ, and we write according to our prophecies, that our children may know to what source they may look for a remission of their sins." [Doctrine and Covenants 76:22-24 ](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/dc-testament/dc/76.22-24?lang=eng#21) would also be a nice addition.